# In Vim, what are settings/commands that begin with a prefix (b:, g:)?

Tags: vim

I installed [this plugin](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) with Vundle and noticed that it has some settings (the README calls them variables) like:

```
b:javascript_fold
```

and

```
g:javascript_conceal
```

The README says I, "can add them to your `.vimrc` to enable/disable their features." But I'm not sure how to set them via `:`. These variables are not available through `set` or `echo`, nor are they commands or functions. How can I set/inspect these?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

These are internal variables.

You create and modify them with the `:let` command:

```
:let g:var_name = 1
```

You destroy them with `:unlet`.

You inspect them with `:echo`.

The prefix shows the scope of the variable; from `:help internal-variables`:

```
buffer-variable    b:    Local to the current buffer.
window-variable    w:    Local to the current window.
tabpage-variable   t:    Local to the current tab page.
global-variable    g:    Global.
local-variable     l:    Local to a function.
script-variable    s:    Local to a |:source|'ed Vim script.
function-argument  a:    Function argument (only inside a function).
vim-variable       v:    Global, predefined by Vim.
```

Adding that kind of variable to your `~/.vimrc` goes like this:

```
let g:var_name = 1
```

Usually, only global variables are to be added to your `~/.vimrc`, buffer-local variables are to be used in filetype plugins.

Comment: For completeness: with no prefix: 
In a function: local to a function; otherwise: global

Answer (score 12):

Configuration variables are not options, they only "emulate" those for plugins. Therefore, you don't use `:set`, but `:let` (and `:echo` to list their current value).

The sigil in front of the variable determines its scope. `g:` means global; those usually need to be set *before* the plugin is loaded, i.e. by placing

```
let g:javascript_conceal = 1
```

into your `~/.vimrc` (and restarting Vim).

As some configuration applies only to certain *filetypes*, these use the `b:` prefix. Setting them in `~/.vimrc` would just apply them to the first opened buffer, which is not what you want. Instead, you need to hook into the *filetype detection* mechanism.

If you only want to enable a config option for certain filetypes, use `:let b:var = value` instead, and put the corresponding commands into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`, where `{filetype}` is the actual filetype (e.g. `javascript`). (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`; use of the *after* directory allows you to override any default filetype settings done by `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.)

Alternatively, you could define an `:autocmd FileType {filetype} setlocal option=value` directly in your `~/.vimrc`, but this tends to become unwieldy once you have many customizations.

```
autocmd Filetype javascript let b:javascript_fold = 1
```